# Creating a variable based off of matching conditions in two datasets

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm attempting to create a variable in one long dataset (df1) where the value in each row needs to be based off of matching some conditions in another long dataset (df2).  The conditions are:
- match on "name"
- the value for df1 should consider observations for that person that occurred before the observation in df1.
- Then I need the number of rows within that subset that meet a third condition (in the data below called "condition")

I've already tried running a for loop (I know, not preferred in R) to write it for each row in 1:nrow(df1), but I keep running into an issue that in my actual data, df1 and df2 are not the same length or a multiple.

I've also tried writing a function and applying it to df1. I tried applying it using apply, but I can't accept two dataframes in the apply syntax. I tried giving it a list of dataframes and using lapply, but it returns back null values.

Here is some generic data that fits the format of the data I'm working with.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Smith", "Jane Smith"),
  date_b = sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2019/10/01'), by="day"), 4))

df2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Smith", "Jane Smith"),
  date_a = sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2019/10/01'), by="day"), 4),
  condition = c("A", "B", "C", "A")
)
```

I know the way to get the number of rows could look something like this:

```
num_conditions <- nrow(df2[which(df1$nam== df2$name & df2$date_a < df1$date_b & df2$condition == "A"), ])
```

What I would like to see in df1 would would be a column called "num_conditions" that would show the number of observations in df2 for that person that occurred before date_b in df1 and met condition "A".

df1 should look like this:

```
name          date_b    num_conditions
John Smith    10/1/15           1
John Smith    11/15/16          0
John Smith    9/19/19           0
```

Comment: This sounds like an example of a "non-equi" join on date, for which there are many examples on this site using `data.table` or `fuzzyjoin` or `sqldf`.

Comment: Tutorial of all three here: https://www.mango-solutions.com/blog/in-between-a-rock-and-a-conditional-join

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways to approach including `data.table`, but here is one using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12)

df2 %>%
  filter(condition == "A") %>%
  right_join(df1, by = "name") %>%
  group_by(name, date_b) %>%
  filter(date_a < date_b) %>%
  mutate(num_conditions = n()) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("name", "date_b")) %>%
  mutate(num_conditions = coalesce(num_conditions, 0L)) %>%
  select(-c(date_a, condition)) %>%
  distinct()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   name, date_b [4]
  name       date_b     num_conditions
  <fct>      <date>              <int>
1 John Smith 2016-10-13              2
2 John Smith 2015-11-10              2
3 Jane Smith 2016-07-18              1
4 Jane Smith 2018-03-13              1

R> df1
        name     date_b
1 John Smith 2016-10-13
2 John Smith 2015-11-10
3 Jane Smith 2016-07-18
4 Jane Smith 2018-03-13

R> df2
        name     date_a condition
1 John Smith 2015-04-16         A
2 John Smith 2014-09-27         A
3 Jane Smith 2017-04-25         C
4 Jane Smith 2015-08-20         A
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is what the question is asking for.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(condition == 'A'), by = 'name') %>%
  filter(date_a < date_b) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(num_conditions = n()) %>%
  select(-date_a, -condition) %>%
  full_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(num_conditions = ifelse(is.na(num_conditions), 0, num_conditions))
#Joining, by = c("name", "date_b")
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   name [2]
#  name       date_b     num_conditions
#  <fct>      <date>              <dbl>
#1 John Smith 2019-05-07              2
#2 John Smith 2019-02-05              2
#3 Jane Smith 2016-05-03              0
#4 Jane Smith 2018-06-23              0
```